An extension of Lehmer's conjecture on Ramanujan's tau function
For a finite additive abelian group $G$, its Davenport constant $D(G)$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that for any $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in G$ there is a nonempty subset $I$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ satisfying $\sum_{i\in I}a_i=0$. There are lots of research works on such zero-sum problems.
Recall that Ramanujan's tau function is given by
$$q\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n)^{24}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\tau(n)q^n\quad \ (|q|<1).$$
Lehmer's conjecture on the tau function states that $\tau(n)\not=0$
for any positive integer $n$. Motivated by the topic of zero-sum problems, I pose the following conjecture which extends the Lehmer conjecture.
Conjecture. For any finite nonempty subset $I$ of $\mathbb Z^+=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, we have $\sum_{i\in I}\tau(i)\not=0.$
I have done some computations via Mathematica, and haven't found any counterexample.
As Lehmer's conjecture remains open, it should be difficult to confirm the above conjecture.
QUESTION. Can one find a counterexample to the conjecture?
Your comments are welcome!
Edits. (i) In the initial version, I also asked whether all the finite sums
$$\sum_{i\in I}\tau(i)\ \ \ \ \text{with}\ I\subseteq\mathbb Z^+\ \text{and}\ |I|<\infty$$
are pariwise distinct. The MO user te4 wrote that this is false due to asymptotic reasons. I have found that
$$\tau(1)+\tau(2)+\tau(9)+\tau(10)+\tau(12)=-600530=\tau(6)+\tau(7)+\tau(13).$$
Perhaps, all the sums $\sum_{\in I}\tau(i)$ with $I\subseteq\mathbb Z^+$ and $|I|\le 4$ are pairwise distinct. I believe that $\tau(1),\tau(2),\tau(3),\ldots$ are pairwise distinct; is this known? I have verified that the numbers $\tau(n)\ (n=1,\ldots,2\times10^5)$ are pairwise distinct.
(ii) Let's define the rank of the tau function as the maximal positive integer $k$ such that $\sum_{i\in I}\tau(i)\not=0$ for all nonempty $I\subset \mathbb Z^+$ with $|I|\le k$. What's the exact value of rank($\tau$) (the rank of the tau function)?

How far have your numerical tests gone?

Not very far as I only checked Conjecture 1 at the Nanjing airport today. I haven't checked Conjecture 2 seriously. Maybe you have a chance to find a counterexample to Conjecture 2.

Conjecture 2 is certainly false due to asymptotic reasons. Take some large $N$. Suppose all $\sum_{s\in S}\tau(s)$ are pairwise distinct for all $2^N-1$ subsets $\emptyset\ne S\subset{1,\ldots,N}$. But $|\sum_{s\in S}\tau(s)|\le|S|\max_{s\in S}|\tau(s)|\le N^{13/2+\varepsilon}$, since $|\tau(n)|\le n^{11/2+\varepsilon}$. So, there are at least $2^N-1$ integers in $[-N^{13/2+\varepsilon};N^{13/2+\varepsilon}]$, absurd for like $N\approx40$

Yes, I have just found a counterexample to Conjecture 2.

I just found that $|{\sum_{i\in I}\tau(i):\ I\subseteq{1,\ldots,13}}|=8120<2^{13}$.

In view of Hou's counterexamples, a new question arises naturally: Whether for any nonempty set $I$ of positive integers with $|I|\le 24$ we have $\sum_{i\in I}\tau(i)\not=0$ ?

One of Hou's counterexamples has $|I|=9$ so maybe you mean $|I| \leq 8$. Simple probabilistic heuristics suggest this should probably be true for $|I|\leq 5$ but admit counterexamples with $|I|=6$.

@Will Sawin  Thank you for your comments! We may define  rank($\tau)$ as the maximal positive integer $k$ such that  $\sum_{i\in I}\tau(i)\not=0$ for any nonempty $I\subset\mathbb Z^+$ with $|I|\le k$. Hou's examples indicate that rank$(\tau)\le 8$.

The conjecture holds for $\max I \le 24$, but there are three counterexamples when $\max I = 25$:
\begin{align*}
I &= \{3, 6, 7, 9, 14, 15, 18, 24, 25\}\qquad\text{or}\\ 
I &= \{1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 11, 15, 16, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25\}\qquad\text{or}\\
I &= \{2, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 18, 19, 20, 23, 25\}.
\end{align*}
